# SharePoint Edit Grid on load without clicking on the edit button

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, document-library, quick-edit, gridview

I want to not have to click on edit rather open the grid in editable mode using JS.

I inherited JS script which for the most part self explanatory but I am new to SharePoint and have been looking for a way to manipulate the edit button to reduce number of clicks in edit a grid, this is where I think the action should happen to indicate that if edit then make the grid editable and the button to show save after edits are done.

```
function SetOrgFilter(OrgFilter) 
{
    console.log('SetOrgFilter');
    var tOrgVal = OrgFilter.val();
    console.log('OrgFilter:'+OrgFilter.val());
    //OrgFilter.val(jQuery_1_12_4('.ms-heroCommandLink:contains(edit)').on( "load", function()));
    
    console.log('g_hidSaveGroup.val():'+g_hidSaveGroup.val());
    console.log('c_PromoteChar:'+c_PromoteChar);

    if (g_hidSaveGroup.val() == '') {
        g_sUserGroups = jQuery_1_12_4("[id*='ddlGroups']  option:selected").text();
        g_hidSaveGroup.val(g_sUserGroups);
    } else {
        g_sUserGroups = g_hidSaveGroup.val().replace(c_PromoteChar,'');
        
        console.log('g_sUserGroups'+g_sUserGroups);
        console.log('tOrgVal:'+tOrgVal);
    }
    
    if(tOrgVal != g_sUserGroups){

        OrgFilter.val(g_hidSaveGroup.val().replace(c_PromoteChar,''));
        
       __doPostBack("input[id*='ctl00_ctl34_g_1ef799c4_672b_4bb3_b9f4_24dcf3b48f10_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl']",'');
    }
   
   OrgFilter.prop("disabled", true); 
   //ChangeEditLink();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new view and choose 'Datasheet View' instead of 'Standard View'

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your requirements, you need to create a **Datasheet view** in your list.

> This view displays list and library items in a grid, similar to a spreadsheet. This view, also known as Quick Edit, can be helpful if you have to edit many items in a list or library at the same time. This view is also helpful if you want to export your data to a spreadsheet or database program.

To read more about how to create Datasheet view in list, please check below article:

[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9).

Also read the "Types of view you can choose section" in this article.